# Unique Cross Join in SQL Table

Tags: mysql, sql, reporting-services, reportbuilder, cross-join

I'm trying to join two 'tables' in SQL in order to use the different columns to represent different parts of a line chart in SSRS Report Builder, including a shaded range, median line and a plotted line of results so it looks like the below image.

[image: Expected outcome]

I have one table with data to display a shaded range on the graph and a median line based on age.

Example Table 1,

```
+---------+-----------------+------------+------------+
| Age     | LowerRange      | UpperRange | Median     |
+---------+-----------------+------------+------------+
| 6       | 100             | 120        | 1          |
| 8       | 200             | 400        | 4          |
| 10      | 300             | 700        | 7          |
| 12      | 400             | 1100       | 1          |
| 14      | 500             | 4000       | 4          |
| 16      | 600             | 7000       | 7          |
| 18      | 700             | 11000      | 1          |
| 20      | 800             | 40000      | 4          |
| 22      | 900             | 70000      | 7          |
+---------+-----------------+------------+------------+
```

I then have a query that joins a few tables into one table that produces results to plot on this graph as a dotted line plot.

Example Table 2,

```
+---------+-------+
| Age     | Value |
+---------+-------+
| 8       | 150   |
| 9       | 270   |
| 14      | 530   |
| 22      | 980   |
+---------+-------+
```

I cannot use two datasets on one single chart, so I decided to cross join the two tables, but it presents me with a table like this;
Table 3

```
+---------+-----------------+------------+------------+---------+-------+
| Age     | LowerRange      | UpperRange | Median     | Res.Age | Value |
+---------+-----------------+------------+------------+---------+-------+
| 6       | 100             | 120        | 1          | 8       | 150   |
| 6       | 100             | 120        | 1          | 9       | 270   |
| 6       | 100             | 120        | 1          | 14      | 530   |
| 6       | 100             | 120        | 1          | 22      | 980   |
| 8       | 200             | 400        | 4          | 8       | 150   |
| 8       | 200             | 400        | 4          | 9       | 270   |
| 8       | 200             | 400        | 4          | 14      | 530   |
| 8       | 200             | 400        | 4          | 22      | 980   |
| 10      | 300             | 700        | 7          | 8       | 150   |
| 10      | 300             | 700        | 7          | 9       | 270   |
| 10      | 300             | 700        | 7          | 14      | 530   |
| 10      | 300             | 700        | 7          | 22      | 980   |
| 12      | 400             | 1100       | 1          | 8       | 150   |
| 12      | 400             | 1100       | 1          | 9       | 270   |
| 12      | 400             | 1100       | 1          | 14      | 530   |
| 12      | 400             | 1100       | 1          | 22      | 980   |
| 14      | 500             | 4000       | 4          | 8       | 150   |
| 14      | 500             | 4000       | 4          | 9       | 270   |
| 14      | 500             | 4000       | 4          | 14      | 530   |
| 14      | 500             | 4000       | 4          | 22      | 980   |
```

How can I combine the tables 1 and 2 to produce a single table with zero duplicates like table 4 below?

Example of expected output,
Table 4

```
+---------+-----------------+------------+------------+---------+-------+
| Age     | LowerRange      | UpperRange | Median     | Res.Age | Value |
+---------+-----------------+------------+------------+---------+-------+
| 6       | 100             | 120        | 1          | 8       | 150   |
| 8       | 200             | 400        | 4          | 9       | 270   |
| 10      | 300             | 700        | 7          | 14      | 530   |
| 12      | 400             | 1100       | 1          | 22      | 980   |
| 14      | 500             | 4000       | 4          | -       | -     |
| 16      | 600             | 7000       | 7          | -       | -     |
| 18      | 700             | 11000      | 1          | -       | -     |
| 20      | 800             | 40000      | 4          | -       | -     |
| 22      | 900             | 70000      | 7          | -       | -     |
+---------+-----------------+------------+------------+---------+-------+
```

Comment: I could not follow what you are trying to do.

Comment: What could I do to be more clear? I tried to explain the best I could but I guess it is a bit of an odd question.

Comment: Show clearly marked input and output, and then just describe the logic to get from point A to point B.  You have given above _four_ tables, some original, some result sets or intermediates, and it wasn't clear to me what you are doing.

Comment: I want to combine both of the original tables, using a SSRS Report Builder dataset query to produce a single table with no duplicates.

Comment: What rules determine which 'duplicates' should be discarded?

Answer (score 0):

To join two datasets in SSRS you can use `Lookup()` on the both foreign keys. Put a tablix in your report, then link the tablix to `Dataset1`. Put all fields from `Dataset1` in your tablix. To display fields from `Dataset2` use the following expression in the tablix:

```
=Lookup(Fields!Dataset1ID.Value, Fields!Dataset2ID.Value, Fields!Dataset2DisplayedField.Value, "Dataset2")
```

This expression will look for matching `ID´s` and then displays the third argument. You can do this more often to display different fields from `Dataset2`.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance.
It turns out that I had to create a UNION ALL to merge all my data into one table.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this in SSRS directly as you have no way to join the tables as they stand as they don't have a unique key.

As I see it, you have two options. Add a key to each table and then use a lookup within SSRS. **Note:** you cannot use RowNumber() in a calculated column or within the LOOKUP function in SSRS so the keys would have to be supplied directly in the dataset query.

The second, and probably simpler option, it to do this on the server side and use a single dataset. I'm not a MySQL person but I think the following should run OK on MySQL 8.0 or above.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1(Age int, LowerRange int, UpperRange int, Median int);
INSERT INTO Table1(Age, LowerRange, UpperRange, Median) VALUES
(6,100, 120, 1),
(8,200, 400, 4),
(10,300, 700, 7),
(12,400, 1100, 1),
(14,500, 4000, 4),
(16,600, 7000, 7),
(18,700, 11000, 1),
(20,800, 40000, 4),
(22,900, 70000, 7);

CREATE TABLE Table2(Age int, Value int);
INSERT INTO Table2(Age, Value) VALUES
(8, 150),
(9, 270),
(14, 530),
(22, 980);

SELECT 
        * 
    FROM 
        (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Age) rn FROM Table1) x
        LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Age) rn FROM Table2) y
            ON x.rn = y.rn
```

This will return the exact results you showed in your example (plus the row numbers which you can obviously exclude if you like)

Here's a fiddle for the above to demonstrate.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bMVF9Co46dhAip5GHuofAw/0

Comment: Thank you for your assistance.
It turns out that I had to create a UNION ALL to merge all my data into one table.